# In Python 3.5 what should the return type annotation look like for a generator function?

Tags: python-3.x, types, python-3.5

```
def a_generator() -> Generator[Tuple[int, int]]:
    # blah blah blah.  
    # Do some stuff to make some ints.
    yield int_one, int_two
```

Did I do that return type annotation correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could use:

```
def a_generator() -> Iterator[Tuple[int, int]]:
    # blah blah blah.  
    # Do some stuff to make some ints.
    yield int_one, int_two
```

[Per Guido's comment here](https://github.com/JukkaL/mypy/issues/695)

From the `Generator` example [in PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-typing-module), it looks like `Generator` takes three arguments.

Also see the documentation for the [typing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator) module.